# Spacex rocket supporting mechanism on the launch pad

Tags: launchpad, launch-system

From the video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPYOtCFSLKw&t=0m7s), it was not clear that how Spacex is supporting their rockets on launch pad. What is the supporting mechanism they are using?

Comment: @jkavalik! Yeah. I'll check that.

Comment: @jkavalik, can you specify me how the end-effector attaches to the rocket?